# Distribute points evenly on a unit hemisphere

Tags: algorithm, geometry, sampling

To distribute point evenly on a unit sphere, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere/26127012#26127012) uses a Fibonacci spiral that maintains constant surface area.

Is it now possible to use a similar method to distribute points evenly on a unit hemisphere without rejecting points? Taking the absolute value like

```
cos_theta = abs(((i * offset) - 1) + (offset / 2))
```

does not work as it seems to cluster the points in pairs.

Comment: see [sphere triangulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214) just init the mesh with its half. also the linked Q/A provides additional methods to solve this ...

Comment: @Spektre sphere triangulation is also an option I considered, it is easier to reason about but the overhead of tesselating the sphere seems larger

Comment: There are also 2 links (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25031737/2521214) with different approach similar to yours but without spiral exploiting spherical coordinates and circle circumference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `y` values loop from `-1+1/samples` to `1-1/samples` by means of the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(samples):
    y = ((i * offset) - 1) + (offset / 2)
```

You want to loop from `0+1/samples` to `1-1/samples`. Simply skip the first `sample/2` iterations:

```
for i in range(samples / 2, samples):
    y = ((i * offset) - 1) + (offset / 2)
```

---

Of course it is cleaner to now rewrite the expressions a bit, such that you loop from `0` to `samples'` again, but this should be a good starting point for more refactoring.