# Number of points in UV sphere

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh, uv-mapping

I'm trying to generate a mesh from a sphere of radius `r`. My goal is to create a UV sphere such that every point on the polyhedron has distance from the sphere smaller than `tol`.

The following code creates a grid of points on the sphere. How can I compute `parallels_count` and `meridians_count` so that all the point of the mesh are within tolerance?

```
  for j in parallels_count:
     parallel = PI * (j+1) / parallels_count
  for i in meridians_count:
     meridian = 2.0 * PI * i / meridians_count
  return spherical_to_cartesian(meridian, parallel)
```

The code comes from [here](https://gamedevdaily.io/four-ways-to-create-a-mesh-for-a-sphere-d7956b825db4#.qki7prhy3), and this is a picture of the UV sphere:

[image: this]

The distance between each face of the mesh and the sphere will be maximum around the center of the face.
So, for the distance between a face and the sphere to be smaller than `tol` it is not sufficient that the distances between the edges of the face and the corresponding circumferences are smaller than `tol`.
This picture is out of context but helps me explaining what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Hello why don't you use the parametric equation of a sphere which is `x = r*cos(u)*cos(v) ` with `-PI <= u <= PI ; -PI/2 <= v <= PI/2` and `y = r*sin(u)*cos(v)` and `z=r*cos(v)` ?

Comment: Hi, I think that's what the method `spherical_to_cartesian()` does. `parallel` and `meridian` are like your `u` and `v`.

Answer (score 1):

the biggest distance between points is on equator so use circle circumference to obtain angular step if I am not mistaken it should be...

```
dangle = tol/r; //[rad]
```

where `r` is sphere radius in the same units as `tol` you can use smaller step to be sure like `dangle*=0.75;` use this for both `parallel` and `meridian` angles.

If you want your counts instead then try:

```
meridians_count = (2.0*PI*r/tol)+1; // ceil or +1 just to be sure
parallels_count = 0.5*meridians_count;
```

It is still early here so I hope I did not make any silly math mistake (the easiest stuff is the worst for silly bugs).

Also take a look at few related **QA**'s of mine:

- [Applying map of the earth texture a Sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31804515/2521214)
- [Make a sphere with equidistant vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031737/2521214)
- [Sphere triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214)

**[Edit1] well your new definition of `tol` changes everything**

I see it like this:

[image: tol]

```
sin(da/2) = (r-tol)/r
da = 2.0*asin((r-tol)/r)
```

If you convert to sphericalsurface than max difference is in center of uv grid cell which represents `sqrt(2)*da`diagonal so try to use:

```
da = sqrt(2.0)*asin((r-tol)/r)
```

so your angle step should be a bit smaller than that ...

Comment: Thanks @Spektre, but dividing the equator's length by `tol` you get `meridians_count` arcs of length equal to `tol`. 
I can't find a 3D picture, but referring to [this](http://arcmaster.ca/working-with-arcs/determine-rise/) 2D picture, you are getting an "arc length" of `tol` while I'm looking for the 3D equivalent of "rise" to be of length <`tol`.

Comment: Hi @Spektre, thank you again! I modified the question hoping that it makes the definition of `tol` clearer. 
Applying the 2D approach both on the U and V directions, the mesh might not be within tolerance in the center of some quadrilateral faces.

Comment: @sgiulia I mean use for sphere `da <= sqrt(2.0)*asin((r-tol)/r)`