# How to map a 3d model's vertices to a spherical surface?

Tags: graphics, 3d

Assume I have a spherical surface with n vertices, and I have a 3d model with m vertices（m<=n）, how can I map this m vertices to this spherical surface（one vertex on the 3d model map to one vertex on the spherical surface）?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? Can multiple model vertices map onto the same sphere vertex? Should vertex proximity be preserved? (for as much as that is possible)

Comment: There are n!/(n-m)! mappings assuming you don't want multiple model vertices mapped to the same spherical vertex. Which one you choose is up to you. Do you have any other criteria to satisfy?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I have not other criteria to satisfy. So I ask this question to get a reasonable solution

Comment: @Botje Two model vertices can't map onto the same sphere vertex. And vertex proximity is not important, I just want that each vertex on the model correspond to only one distinctive vertex on the spherical surface

Comment: Then map model point 1 to sphere point 1, 2 to 2, and so on. Are you sure you have no unstated criteria or preferences?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I think I can  generate a ray from the model center and a point of model, then the ray intersect with sphere, finally find the point of sphere closest to the  intersection point.

Comment: @coca666 yep just like this [cube to sphere conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61770981/2521214)