# Generate hexagon lattices graph on the world using Networkx

Tags: networking, graph, path, networkx, hexagonal-tiles

I want to generate a hexagon grid on the ocean for finding a shortest path.

Networkx provides [lattice.hexagonal_lattice_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.lattice.hexagonal_lattice_graph.html#networkx.generators.lattice.hexagonal_lattice_graph) which generates a graph whose nodes and edges are the hexagonal tiling of the plane.

However, I do not want to search along the edges of the hexagons, but I would like to consider the hexagons as nodes and the 6 adjacent hexagons as the neighboring nodes. In this way, there are 6 search directions from a node, as shown in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MFru.png).

To apply this on a ship routing problem, I would generate such a graph for the earth and exclude all hexagon tiles inside land polygons, and divide the hexagons intersecting with the land polygon borders into smaller hexagons, creating a higher graph density in coastal areas.

How do I create such a hexagonal tiling graph, such that each node has edges in the six directions with Networkx?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777626/mathematically-producing-sphere-shaped-hexagonal-grid).

I recursively subdivided triangles of an icosahedron into smaller triangles as done in this [blog](http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html). 
Then used Networkx to construct a graph of the vertices and edges.