# How to calculate the position of the center of each hexagon on an icosphere?

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I'm coding a game with an (not so original) idea of having a procedurally generated map with hexagons. The plot twist is that the map will generate over a sphere.

Calm down [Euler](https://www.redblobgames.com/x/1640-hexagon-tiling-of-sphere/)! I know that you cannot tile hexagon over a sphere without having 12 pentagon left over, but they will be hidden in the ocean of the planet, so we won't see them.

Now, I want to use [WFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse) to generate the terrain (the hexagons) and I need a grid for this, so I would like a function that **takes in parameter the subdivision level** of the icosphere and **return the position of the center of every hexagonal faces** in spherical coordinates (this way it can scale easily! and I just need to ofset the asset from it's parent and rotate it's parent with the theta and phi angles).

Again, I need to be able to change the subdlvl and cannot bake it in, because not only the terrain, but also the size of the planet will be random. And I want a smaller planet to have fewer hexagons, while a bigger one should have a higher number of hexagons.

Lastly, this is **optional**, but my actual tile mesh is 2m wide, so it could be great if I could calculate the optimal subd level of the icosphere (the one that streches the tile the least) given the radius of the planet and the size of the tile. Again this is not the main question, All I really need for now is something working, I'll concentrate on those details later.

Thank you everyone!
Have a great day

PS: sorry for the tags, I really had no idea what I could put

Comment: https://www.freelancer.com/hire/python

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455940/1725562

Comment: why not taking a look at Uber's H3 spatial index based on hexagons? https://www.uber.com/en-PL/blog/h3/
The interactive viewer is here: https://wolf-h3-viewer.glitch.me/
There are APIs for popular languages: https://h3geo.org/docs/api/indexing
This is open source and available here: https://github.com/uber/h3

Perhaps you can just port some ideas or take the whole concept :)