# How to animate a rotatable fluffy ball in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, gpgpu

### Idea came from

Instagram @sennepldn

[Fluffy ball demo (from Instagram)](https://www.instagram.com/p/CIETspCByeZ/)

[Fluffy ball demo (If you can't access Instagram Link)](https://youtu.be/aCmoWuPxQ-M)

[image: preview]

When I saw this example three days ago, I was very surprised, so I wanted to challenge myself and try to make this effect.

After three days, I have tried many ways like using vertex shader or GPUComputationRenderer, but still did not make the correct simulation. So I finally decided to come up and ask you all.

---

### My Solution

#### Step 1

First, use the following two balls that seem to have hard spikes to simulate the Fluffy Ball in the Demo.

From the first frame to the second frame, the ball rotated about 30 degrees clockwise (I randomly assumed an angle)

[image: Sketch - Frame1 & Frame2]

#### Step 2

Simplify the upper ball into the picture below.

The black line in the picture represents the longest spike in the picture above.

A1, a2, b1, b2 (Vector3) represent the positions of points a and b at different times.

[image: Sketch - Simplified Frame1 & Frame2 image]

However, in the final simulation, this is a soft hair instead of a hard thorn, so the position of Frame2 b point should be b3.

[image: Sketch - Proper Frame2 point b position]

#### Step 3

So I plan to use the following method to simulate.

FAKE CODE (in vertex shader) (b1, b2, b3 means position in vec3)

```
b3 = mix(b1, b2, 0.9);
```

In order to read the position of point b (b1) of the previous frame, I save the modelMatrix of the previous frame and pass it to the next frame as a uniform.

In the next frame, we can get b1 world position by modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0), however this method is not correct.

For example, in Frame 3, if we want to read the last frame b point position. This method will get b2 instead of b3, but b3 is needed for actual simulation.

Is there any way to get the position of the last frame b point correctly?

I also tried to use GPUComputationRenderer to save the position of the previous frame and put it in a Texture.

But maybe it's because my understanding of GPGPU is still not thorough, and I don't know how to put the world coordinates of the previous frame into the texture and let the next frame read it, so this method did not succeed.

---

### Sum up my question

1. How can I read last frame world position in THREE.js GPGpu? What's the step?
2. Is there any better way to do this simulation? Even if it has nothing to do with my thoughts. For example, simulate real-world forces.

Comment: very interesting question +1 :) will give it a try latter (C++/GLSL) if I come up with something will post an answer. However I would not use previous frame instead I would pass actual speed and rotation as uniforms and do the stuff fully in fragment shader... most likely using ray tracing with this [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214)

Comment: Looking forward to your answer :)
I am also exploring other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to have few **concentric spherical layers of equidistant points** like this:

- [Make a sphere with equidistant vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031737/2521214)

where each layer has its own transformation matrix. At start all the layers have the same [Transformation matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) and after each frame (or simulation timer tick) the matrices are passed (like cyclic ring buffer) so the lowest radius layer has actual matrix, the next one has matrix from previous frame and so on. Its basically **geometric version of motion blur**...

However my attempts to ray tracing this in fragment shader (as merged particles) based on these:

- [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214)
- [Atmospheric scattering GLSL fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214)
- [raytrace through 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)

Hit a wall with accuracy and other math edge cases and rounding problems leading to ugly artifacts which to debug (if even possible) will take forever and porting to 64 bit will solve just a part of the problem...

So I decided to try to create geometry data for this on per frame basis which might be doable in geometry shader (later on). So first I tried to do this on CPU side (C++ and old GL api for now just for simplicity and as a proof of concept)

So I got list of equidistant points on unit sphere surface (static points) which I use to render the layers. So each point is transformed into line strip where the point is just scaled by layer radius and transformed by the matrix of layer it belong to. Here C++ code for this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// just some vector and matrix math needed for this
void  vectorf_mul(float *c,float *a,float  b) { for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=a[i]*b; } // c[3] = a[3]*b
void  matrixf_mul_vector(float *c,float *a,float *b)    // c[3] = a[16]*b[3]
    {
    float q[3];
    q[0]=(a[ 0]*b[0])+(a[ 4]*b[1])+(a[ 8]*b[2])+(a[12]);
    q[1]=(a[ 1]*b[0])+(a[ 5]*b[1])+(a[ 9]*b[2])+(a[13]);
    q[2]=(a[ 2]*b[0])+(a[ 6]*b[1])+(a[10]*b[2])+(a[14]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// equidistant sphere points
const int sphere_na=20;                     // number of slices (latitude)
float sphere_pnt[sphere_na*sphere_na*6];    // equidistant sphere points
int sphere_n=0;                             // 3 * number of points
// create list of equidistant sphere points r=1 center=(0,0,0)
void sphere_init()
    {
    int ia,ib,na=sphere_na,nb;
    float x,y,z,r;
    float a,b,da,db;
    da=M_PI/float(na-1);                    // latitude angle step
    sphere_n=0;
    for (a=-0.5*M_PI,ia=0;ia<na;ia++,a+=da) // slice sphere to circles in xy planes
        {
        r=cos(a);                       // radius of actual circle in xy plane
        z=sin(a);                       // height of actual circle in xy plane
        nb=ceil(2.0*M_PI*r/da);
        if ((ia==0)||(ia==na-1)) { nb=1; db=0.0; }  // handle edge cases
        db=2.0*M_PI/float(nb);             // longitude angle step
        for (b=0.0,ib=0;ib<nb;ib++,b+=db)   // cut circle to vertexes
            {
            x=r*cos(b);                     // compute x,y of vertex
            y=r*sin(b);
            sphere_pnt[sphere_n]=x; sphere_n++;
            sphere_pnt[sphere_n]=y; sphere_n++;
            sphere_pnt[sphere_n]=z; sphere_n++;
            }
        }
    }
// render sphere as lines from center to surface
void sphere_draw()
    {
    int i;
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i=0;i<sphere_n;i+=3)
        {
        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glColor3f(0.5,0.6,0.7); glVertex3fv(sphere_pnt+i);
        }
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// puff ball
const int puff_n=8;                     // number of layers
float *puff_m[puff_n]={NULL};           // transform matrix for each layer
float puff_matrices[puff_n*16];         // transform matrix for each layer
float puff_col[puff_n][3];              // color for each layer
// render sphere as spicules dived to layers
void puff_draw(float r0,float r1)
    {
    int i,j;
    float p[3],*p0,r,dr=(r1-r0)/float(puff_n);
    glColor3f(0.5,0.6,0.7);
    for (i=0;i<sphere_n;i+=3)
        {
        p0=sphere_pnt+i;
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (r=r0,j=0;j<puff_n;j++,r+=dr)
            {
            vectorf_mul(p,p0,r);
            matrixf_mul_vector(p,puff_m[j],p);
            glColor3fv(puff_col[j]);
            glVertex3fv(p);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    }
// update matrices
void puff_update()
    {
    int i;
    float *p,t;
    if (puff_m[0]==NULL)                    // in first pass all the matrices are actual
        {
        for (i=0;i<puff_n;i++)
            {
            puff_m[i]=puff_matrices+(i<<4);
            glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,puff_m[i]);
            t=1.0-(float(i)/float(puff_n-1));
            puff_col[i][0]=0.1+0.3*t;
            puff_col[i][1]=0.2+0.5*t;
            puff_col[i][2]=0.2+0.6*t;
            }
        return;
        }
    p=puff_m[puff_n-1];                     // insert actual matrix to ring FIFO buffer
    for (i=puff_n-1;i>0;i--) puff_m[i]=puff_m[i-1];
    puff_m[0]=p;
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,puff_m[0]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And usage:

```cpp
// init
sphere_init();

// render
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);  // this is just putting ball before my perspective camera
glRotatef(animt,0.0,0.3,0.5); // animt is just changing angle updated in timer
puff_update();  // this will update the matrices in layers (must be called before first draw)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // however render itself is using unit matrix !!!
glLoadIdentity();
puff_draw(0.5,1.0); // render the hairs with radiuses from 0.5 up to 1.0
```

And here preview (for low enough hair count to actually see the geometry):

[image: preview]

As you can see the hairs bend in correct direction (they are affected also by speed and this should be affected also by translation not just rotation as a bonus) so as a proof of concept this approach works. If you want them to bend more just lower the difference between `r0,r1` radiuses.

As you can see this should be possible to port to GLSL geometry shader easily. The CPU just pass the unit sphere points once and geometry will emit a line strip for each point in the same way. You just need to have the matrices as uniforms.

Here another preview with changing rotation and lower `r0,r1` difference:

[image: better preview]

Aside of tweaking the number of points `sphere_na` and layers `puff_n` this can be added to improve things:

- distribute the layers between `r0,r1` non linearly to achieve different look/behavior
- add sphere surface (`r0` so you do not see the hairs behind it)
- textures
- motion blur
- variable hair width (so at base its more wide)
- light model (maybe just for the surface and not for the hairs itself)

I think this might be used for improvement (curvature and variable width):

- [GLSL rendering 2D cubic BEZIER curves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214)

**[Edit1] some tweaks and geometry shader**

I succesfully ported this to shaders and added some stuff like colors, line width and inner sphere surface. Here the full VCL/C++/OpenGL/GLSL code:

**VCL app window (just ignore the VCL stuff)**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float animx=0.0;
float animy=0.0;
bool _glsl=true;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// just some vector and matrix math needed for this
void  vectorf_mul(float *c,float *a,float  b) { for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=a[i]*b; } // c[3] = a[3]*b
void  matrixf_mul_vector(float *c,float *a,float *b)    // c[3] = a[16]*b[3]
    {
    float q[3];
    q[0]=(a[ 0]*b[0])+(a[ 4]*b[1])+(a[ 8]*b[2])+(a[12]);
    q[1]=(a[ 1]*b[0])+(a[ 5]*b[1])+(a[ 9]*b[2])+(a[13]);
    q[2]=(a[ 2]*b[0])+(a[ 6]*b[1])+(a[10]*b[2])+(a[14]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// equidistant sphere points
const int sphere_na=30;                     // number of slices (latitude)
float sphere_pnt[sphere_na*sphere_na*4];    // equidistant sphere points (approx size <= regular grid size / 1.5)
int sphere_n=0;                             // 3 * number of points
int sphere_slc[sphere_na+1];                // start index of each slice
// create list of equidistant sphere points r=1 center=(0,0,0)
void sphere_init()
    {
    int ia,ib,na=sphere_na,nb;
    float x,y,z,r;
    float a,b,da,db;
    da=M_PI/float(na-1);                    // latitude angle step
    sphere_n=0;
    for (a=-0.5*M_PI,ia=0;ia<na;ia++,a+=da) // slice sphere to circles in xy planes
        {
        sphere_slc[ia]=sphere_n;
        r=cos(a);                       // radius of actual circle in xy plane
        z=sin(a);                       // height of actual circle in xy plane
        nb=ceil(2.0*M_PI*r/da);
        if ((ia==0)||(ia==na-1)) { nb=1; db=0.0; }  // handle edge cases
        db=2.0*M_PI/float(nb);             // longitude angle step
        for (b=0.0,ib=0;ib<nb;ib++,b+=db)   // cut circle to vertexes
            {
            x=r*cos(b);                     // compute x,y of vertex
            y=r*sin(b);
            sphere_pnt[sphere_n]=x; sphere_n++;
            sphere_pnt[sphere_n]=y; sphere_n++;
            sphere_pnt[sphere_n]=z; sphere_n++;
            }
        }
    sphere_slc[na]=sphere_n;
    }
void sphere_gl_draw(float r)
    {
    int i,i0,i1,i2,n,n0,n1,j,k;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(r,r,r);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (k=1;k<sphere_na;k++)
        {
        i0=sphere_slc[k-1];
        i1=sphere_slc[k+0];
        i2=sphere_slc[k+1];
        n0=(i1-i0)/3;
        n1=(i2-i1)/3;
        n=n0; if (n<n1) n=n1;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            j=i0+(3*((i*n0)/n));
            glNormal3fv(sphere_pnt+j);
            glVertex3fv(sphere_pnt+j);
            j=i1+(3*((i*n1)/n));
            glNormal3fv(sphere_pnt+j);
            glVertex3fv(sphere_pnt+j);
            }
        }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// puff ball
float r0=0.80,r1=1.0;                   // hair radiuses
const int puff_n=16;                        // number of layers (the more the more its bendy like)
float *puff_m[puff_n]={NULL};           // transform matrix for each layer
float puff_matrices[puff_n*16];         // transform matrix for each layer
float puff_col[puff_n*3];               // color for each layer
// render sphere as spicules dived to layers
void puff_gl_draw(float r0,float r1)
    {
    int i,j;
    float p[3],*p0,r,dr=r1-r0;
    float t,dt=1.0/float(puff_n);
    glColor3f(0.5,0.6,0.7);
    for (i=0;i<sphere_n;i+=3)
        {
        p0=sphere_pnt+i;
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (t=0.0,j=0;j<puff_n;j++,t+=dt)
            {
            r=r0+t*dr;
            vectorf_mul(p,p0,r);
            matrixf_mul_vector(p,puff_m[j],p);
            glColor3fv(puff_col+j+j+j);
            glVertex3fv(p);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    }
void puff_glsl_draw(float r0,float r1)
    {
    int i;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i=0;i<sphere_n;i+=3)
        {
        glVertex3fv(sphere_pnt+i);
        }
    glEnd();
    }
// update matrices
void puff_update()
    {
    int i;
    float *p,t;
    if (puff_m[0]==NULL)                    // in first pass all the matrices are actual
        {
        for (i=0;i<puff_n;i++)
            {
            puff_m[i]=puff_matrices+(i<<4);
            glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,puff_m[i]);
            t=float(i)/float(puff_n-1);
            puff_col[i+i+i+0]=0.1+0.1*t;
            puff_col[i+i+i+1]=0.1+0.2*t;
            puff_col[i+i+i+2]=0.1+0.4*t;
            }
        return;
        }
    p=puff_m[puff_n-1];                     // insert actual matrix to ring FIFO buffer
    for (i=puff_n-1;i>0;i--) puff_m[i]=puff_m[i-1];
    puff_m[0]=p;
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,puff_m[0]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // animate matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0*r1);
    glRotatef(animx,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(animy,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    puff_update();

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColor3f(0.4,0.2,0.1);
    sphere_gl_draw(r0);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glLineWidth(3.0);
    if (_glsl)
        {
        GLint id;
        glUseProgram(prog_id);
        id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"r0"); glUniform1f(id,r0);
        id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"r1"); glUniform1f(id,r1);
        id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"n" ); glUniform1i(id,puff_n);
        // pass ring FIFO of matrices in their order
        // can be improved by passing start index instead of reordering
        int i,j,k;
        float m[16*puff_n];
        for (k=0,i=0;i<puff_n;i++)
         for (j=0;j<16;j++,k++)
          m[k]=puff_m[i][j];
        id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"mv"); glUniformMatrix4fv(id,puff_n,false,m);
        glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,m);
        id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"mp"); glUniformMatrix4fv(id,1,false,m);
        id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"c" );  glUniform3fv(id,puff_n,puff_col);

        puff_glsl_draw(r0,r1);
        glUseProgram(0);
        }
    else{
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        puff_gl_draw(r0,r1);
        }
    glLineWidth(1.0);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);

    int hnd,siz; char vertex[4096],geom[4096],fragment[4096];
    hnd=FileOpen("puff.glsl_vert",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,vertex  ,siz); vertex  [siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    hnd=FileOpen("puff.glsl_geom",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,geom    ,siz); geom    [siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    hnd=FileOpen("puff.glsl_frag",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,fragment,siz); fragment[siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    glsl_init(vertex,geom,fragment);
//  hnd=FileCreate("GLSL.txt"); FileWrite(hnd,glsl_log,glsl_logs); FileClose(hnd);

    int i0,i;
    mm_log->Lines->Clear();
    for (i=i0=0;i<glsl_logs;i++)
     if ((glsl_log[i]==13)||(glsl_log[i]==10))
        {
        glsl_log[i]=0;
        mm_log->Lines->Add(glsl_log+i0);
        glsl_log[i]=13;
        for (;((glsl_log[i]==13)||(glsl_log[i]==10))&&(i<glsl_logs);i++);
        i0=i;
        }
    if (i0<glsl_logs) mm_log->Lines->Add(glsl_log+i0);

    sphere_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_exit();
    glsl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight-mm_log->Height);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    animx+=1.5; if (animx>=360.0) animx=-360.0;
    animy+=2.5; if (animy>=360.0) animy=-360.0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
    {
    _glsl=!_glsl;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `gl_simple.h` can be found in here:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

However the version posted there is old (the one I used has added geometry shader support...) Here the shaders:

```cpp
// Vertex
#version 400 core
in  vec3 pos;
void main()
    {
    gl_Position=vec4(pos,1.0);
    }
```

```cpp
// Geometry
#version 400 core
layout(points) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices = 32) out;

uniform int n;          // hair layers
uniform float r0;       // min radius for hairs
uniform float r1;       // max radius for hairs
uniform mat4 mp;        // global projection
uniform mat4 mv[32];    // hair modelview per layer
uniform vec3 c[32];     // color per layer

out vec3 col;
void main()
    {
    int i;
    vec3 p;
    float r,dr=(r1-r0)/float(n-1);
    // input just single point
    p=gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    // emit line strip
    for (r=r0,i=0;i<n;i++,r+=dr)
        {
        col=c[i];
        gl_Position=mp*mv[i]*vec4(p.xyz*r,1.0);
        EmitVertex();
        }
    EndPrimitive();
    }
```

```cpp
// Fragment
#version 400 core
in vec3 col;
out vec4 fcol;
void main()
    {
    fcol=vec4(col,1.0);
    }
```

The VCL app is just simple window with one 40ms update timer and memo for GLSL logs so ignore tha and or mimic the VCL events in your environment. The `_glsl` just determines if shaders are used or not. This is far from optimized there is a lot of stuff to improve like using VAO instead `glBegin/glEnd`, recoding the matrix ring buffer so it does not need to reorder, etc ...

**And finally new preview:**

[image: new preview]

Comment: Amazing!!
I'm trying another method that I thought of yesterday, but that has its drawbacks even if it succeeds.
It seems that your method is better than mine. After I finish the ongoing trial, I will try your method.
I will update the follow-up results

Comment: @JamesLu I added edit1 to my answer check it out ... textures and some randomnes might improve the look even more however I am too lazy to play with that... looking forward for some screenshots of yours (you can post your approach as answer too).