# Creating a phillotaxic sphere / hemisphere with C#?

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to follow a tutorial which is written in a math programming language I'm not familiar with and attempting to convert the tutorial to C# code for Unity 3d.

See here: http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/

```
    float theta = Mathf.PI * (3 - Mathf.Sqrt(5));
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        float r = (radius / 2) * Mathf.Sqrt(i) / Mathf.Sqrt(points);
        float a = theta * i;

        Vector3 coords = transform.TransformDirection( new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(a) * r, 0, Mathf.Sin(a) * r) )+transform.position;

        spawnPoints[i] = coords;
    }
```

This if course generates the flat phillotaxic arrangement in 2d. I'm trying to modify Y (up) axis for depth (creating the sphere).

I cannot seem to set the Y (up) axis correctly in proportion with i and radius.

Considering the tutorial above, how should I be calculating Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3D version is called a *spherical Fibonacci lattice*. [This paper](http://www.geonaut.eu/published/2010_Gonzalez__Measurement_of_areas_on_a_sphere_using_Fibonacci_and_latitude-longitude_lattices.pdf) gives a nice explanation. [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363178/is-the-fibonacci-lattice-the-very-best-way-to-evenly-distribute-n-points-on-a-sp) has more links.

Comment: And that's all she/he wrote! Thank you very much!