# What does operator ./ in python mean

Tags: python, function, operators, fibonacci

I read this question [Evenly distributing n points on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere/26127012#26127012) and in one of the answers in python was used this:

> offset = 2./samples

I was trying to find what does it mean but I didn't succeed.
At first, I thought it is something with directories (./ like in Linux command line) but that doesn't make any sense actually.

If this is too basic or duplicate I am sorry, but I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: It does the same as `offset = (2.)/samples`. `./` is not an operator.

Comment: And that is? I don't know python at all, I have to do something similar in different language.

Comment: Division, as in `offset = 2.0 / samples`.  The `2.0` is (probably) used instead of just 2 to get a floating point answer in the old python version 2.  (In python2, integer 2 would give an integer result if `samples` was an integer).

Comment: Ok, that is simple :), thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `./` operator, the `.` is part of the number. That is you have the number `2.` (which is the same as `2.0`), followed by the `/` operator, followed by `samples`. With spaces, it'd be `2. / samples`.

And, as you know, `/` is the division operator.

Comment: Oh! Great. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth mentioning why the `.` is there in the first place - it's to ensure you get a floating point division rather than an integer one.