# How to transform lat/lon coordinates from degree to km to create a 1 km grid

Tags: python, grid, coordinates, gis, pyproj

I have a dataframe containing lat/lon coordinates in decimal degree.

My goal is to aggregate the data on a rectangular grid of 1 km². For that matter, I transformed my coordinates into km based on the method described in [Convert latitude, longitude to distance from equator in kilometers and round to nearest kilometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673048/convert-latitude-longitude-to-distance-from-equator-in-kilometers-and-round-to)

The method consists in calculating the distance from a reference point to the points (lat=0, lon) and (lat, lon=0).

But it doesn't work, because it seems to depend on the reference point.

By taking my reference point as (lon_ref=mean(lon), lat_ref=mean(lat)), I end up aggregating in the same tile points that are 120km away from each other.

This is the code that I am using :

```
# get the coordinates of my reference point

lat_ref, lon_ref = data["lat"].mean() , data["lon"].mean()

# the distance function

from pyproj import Geod 
wgs84_geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')

format = lambda x: wgs84_geod.inv(lon_ref,lat_ref,0,x)[2]/1000 #km 

format = lambda x: wgs84_geod.inv(lon_ref,lat_ref,x,0)[2]/1000 #km 

# Apply the function on my dataframe

data["londist"]=data['lon'].map(format)

data["latdist"]=data['lat'].map(format)

# round to the nearest km

step=1 # 1km

to_bin = lambda x: np.round(x / step) * step

data["latbin"] = data['latdist'].map(to_bin)

data["lonbin"] = data['londist'].map(to_bin)
```

This works for some lat/lon but not for others,

Example:

```
point1 (46.9574,4.29949) # lat,lon in °

point2( 46.9972 ,3.18153)
```

Calculate the distance and round using the above code:

```
point1 (latbin = 259 , lonbin=5205)

point2(latbin = 259 , lonbin=5205)
```

The two points will be aggregated together
However, the distance between the two points is 85 km!

```
dist=wgs84_geod.inv(4.29949,46.9574,3.18153,46.9972)[2]/1000
```

How can I solve this problem?
Is there any other efficient method to make the aggregation given that I have 10 millions lat/lon in my dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you assign to `format` variable twice, second assignment erasing first one. Did you mean to have something like `format_lon` and `format_lat`?

Note that once you fix this, the result will still depend on reference point - this is inevitable when you project spherical coordinates to flat map. But the result should be reasonable.