# Alpha Blending with Integer Texture for Object Picking

Tags: rust, shader, webgl, webgl2

**Problem Description**

Hi! In our WebGL application, we are drawing many (even hundreds of thousands) shapes and we want to discover which shape is currently under the mouse. I'm looking for a way to do it in an efficient manner.

**Details**

The shapes are defined with [Signed Distance Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function). Each shape is drawn by applying a predefined sdf fragment shader to a square polygon (2 triangles). Each shape is assigned with a unique ID (`uint`) on the Rust side (we're using WASM here). The idea is to render the scene twice (in WebGL 1.0) or once to multiple render targets (in WebGL 2.0), where one of the targets would be the ID encoded as a color. Then we can use `readPixels` to query the color and get the ID of the shape under the mouse. Unfortunately, every solution that we try has some downsides.

**Requirements**

- We need to encode 2 ints per shape (one to tell us what shape it was, like if it was a button, or maybe a slider), and second to tell us which instance of object it was (e.g. 5th slider).
- We will have a lot of shapes (and instances) on the stage, so for each int we would need at least 24-bit, preferably 32-bit precision.

**What he have tried so far**

- Rendering ID information to `RGBA32UI` texture type. In this solution we are using 32 bits per channel, so we can use 2 channels to represent our IDs. Unfortunately, blending applies only in RGBA mode and only if the color buffer has a fixed-point or floating-point format. We need some form of blending because when drawing shapes, like circles, some parts need to be transparent. In the case of ID color output our alpha is always 0 or 1.
- Rendering ID information to `RGBA` texture and converting `uint` to `float` in GLSL by using [intBitsToFloat](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/intBitsToFloat.xhtml) and then back `float` to `uint` in Rust. Unfortunately, this is available in GLSL 330 and we are limited to GLSL 300 in WebGL.
- Rendering ID information to `RGB32UI` texture and use `discard` for some pixels. This would work but it can cause performance problems and we would rather not like to use it.
- Converting ID information on Rust side to `float`, using it instead of `uint`, and rendering it to `RGBA` texture, and converting it back to `uint` on Rust side. The problem with this solution is that it is pretty complex, we cannot use all of 32-bits (we need to be extra careful about possible NAN-encoding) and we feel there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: What is **alpha** blending supposed to do on an integer texture? I mean, those integers are discrete ID values. How would you *"blend"* between 2 or more IDs?

Comment: In this specific case it is only meant to choose one or the other (we only use an alpha of 0 or 1).

Comment: What I am after is something that can have the same effect as alpha blending for that case, but works in integers.

Comment: Why use RGBUI32? Do you expect to draw 2^96 objects? Even just using RGBA8 would be 4 billion IDs

Comment: At the moment we are using a single channel to encode the ID, which in our application itself is represented as a u32. It seemed the natural fit.

Comment: @gman, ok you are right! In fact using `RGBA8` we will have space for 16,777,216 ids (not 4 billion, as alpha does not count in), but in fact this would be enough for what we need here. Hmm, Im wondering why we were missing such and obvious and simple solution here. We will try that and be back with info here!

Comment: Alpha does count. It's just another channel. It's not special.

Comment: Also FYI, SDFs are generally **not best practice** and are **not preformant**. Every pixel is requiring insane amounts of calculations to figure out if any of the SDFs are in the ray for that pixel. A high perf app (nearly every game you've ever played) does not use SDFs.

Comment: A few other comments. you say you need 2 ints per shape but you could use 1 int per shape and map those ints back to your 2 ids in code. You also say you need 24 to 32bit ids. That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You can't possibly be drawing 16 million to 4 billion objects at any kind of resonable perf. Plus there just aren't that many pixels on the screen. As for RGBA8 no conversion from int to float is required. You put in Uint8 r,g,b,a as Uint32. You read as vec4, you write that vec4, you get back the same Uint8 you put in as Uint32

Comment: Also also, the spec you linked to has absolutely nothing to do with WebGL. It's not wrong but you were just lucky. Like if you asked what's 11 * 2 and someone links [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyoming). It might sound like a rant but the problem is if you link to the wrong specs you lead people to the places where it will not be correct. Please fix your link

Comment: @gman how can you put in uint8 (or 32) to a RGBA8 texture? Doesn't it require uploading floating point uniforms to its vec4?

Comment: oh my mistake, RGBA8 is UNSIGNED_BYTE data format

Comment: oh but it does require converting to/from float for vec4 in the shader..

Answer (score 3):

Blending is considered to be part of the per-fragment functions that require floating point values, hence it has no effect when rendering to unnormalized integer textures.

From [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) section 4.1 lists 9 operations that happen with pixel/fragments.

Section 4.1.7 Blending which is operation 7 of the 9 operations says

> Blending applies only if the color buffer has a fixed-point format. If the color
>   buffer has an integer format, proceed to the next operation.

In other words, the blending operation is skipped if you're using an integer format.

Instead you can simply `discard` the fragment if the alpha value is below a given threshold.

```
if(alpha < 0.5) discard;
output_id = uvec4(input_symbol_id,input_instance_id,0,1);
```

Comment: LJᛃ, @gman , I'm working with Michael (who asked this question) and I have edited it to provide more context. We are afraid of performance penalties of `discard` so we would rather not use it if there is any other solution available. Would you be so nice and take a look at the question again and suggest us if there are other possible solutions? In fact, we have also described one solution that we believe would work there, but we are still looking for something better (if its possible).

Comment: [You only need to render a single pixel to do picking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747996/on-the-browser-how-to-plot-100k-series-with-64-128-points-each/51757743) so there is no perf hit for discard.

Comment: please link to the [correct specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf). OpenGL specs are irrelevant and often wrong for WebGL. Linking to the irrelevant OpenGL specs will lead people to mis-information and frustration which is not cool.

Comment: @gman True but not being able to link the PDFs sections is quite annoying furthermore I wasn't able to find the statement in question in bespoken spec, nor in the WebGL2 spec? Please, if you find it edit the answer accordingly, thanks!