# Is it possible to discard for one draw buffer while still writing to another?

Tags: webgl, webgl2, glsles

The use case is essentially the same as [Alpha Blending with Integer Texture for Object Picking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345380/alpha-blending-with-integer-texture-for-object-picking)

*One* of the answers is to discard fragments that fail the alpha test.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to `discard` for one render target in a framebuffer, while still writing to the others. In my initial attempt of simply not writing the `out` value for that target, it seems to still write the default value (`0`, `uvec4(0)`, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you `discard` then no buffers will be updated, regardless of whether you assigned to the output variable beforehand or not.

> The `discard` keyword is only allowed within fragment shaders. It can be used within a fragment shader to abandon the operation on the current fragment. This keyword causes the fragment to be discarded and **no updates to any buffers** will occur.
>
> – *[The OpenGL ES Shading Language Specification, Page 58](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) (Page 64 in the PDF)*

*(emphasis mine)*

If blending is enabled, then you could write a transparent color to the output that you want to "discard".

```c
// discard;
out = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: On mobile devices, another option is to fetch the colour of the previous fragment (gl_LastFragData/gl_LastFragColorARM). But not all OpenGL ES implementations support this, and in particular I don't think WebGL supports this.