# How can I achieve an even distribution of sprites across the surface of a sphere in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a database of words where the most important words are closer to the top of the sphere and the less important are further away. So I created a sphere with enough vertices for each word, created a list of those vertices in order of distance from the top of the sphere, and placed the text sprites at the positions of the vertices in order of that sorted list.

[image]
Video version: https://i.gyazo.com/aabaf0b4a26f4413dc6a0ebafab2b4bd.mp4

Sounded like a good plan in my head, but clearly the geometry of a sphere causes the words to be further spread out the further away from the top they are. I need a result that looks like a somewhat even distribution across the surface. It doesn't have to be perfect, just visually closer than this.

**How can I achieve the desired effect?**

Here are the relevant methods:

```
positionDb(db) {
    console.log("mostRelated", db.mostRelated);
    console.log("depthList", this.depthList);
    let mostRelated = db.mostRelated;
    let depthList = this.depthList;
    for (let i = 0; i < mostRelated.length; i++) {
      this.addTextNode(mostRelated[i].data, this.depthList[i].vertice, this.depthList[i].depth);
    }

}
addTextNode(text, vert, distance) {
    let fontSize = 0.5 * (600 / distance);
    let sprite = new THREE.TextSprite({
      fillStyle: '#000000',
      fontFamily: '"Arial", san-serif',
      fontSize: fontSize,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      text: text
    });
    this.scene.add(sprite);
    sprite.position.set(vert.x, vert.y, vert.z);
    setTimeout(() => {
        sprite.fontFamily = '"Roboto", san-serif';
    }, 1000)
}


this.scene = scene;
this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(420, 50, 550);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0011ff
});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, wireframe);
var wireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(this.geometry);
let frontVert = {
    x: 0,
    y: 100,
    z: 0
}
let depthList = [];
this.geometry.vertices.forEach(vertice => {
  let depth = getDistance(frontVert, vertice);
  if (depthList.length === 0) {
    depthList.push({
      depth,
      vertice
    });
  } else {
    let flag = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < depthList.length; i++) {
      let item = depthList[i];
      if (depth < item.depth) {
        flag = true;
        depthList.splice(i, 0, {
          depth,
          vertice
        });
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!flag) depthList.push({
      depth,
      vertice
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What you want is a geometry different to the default `THREE.SphereGeometry`. There are plenty of articles about this around. It's a difficult topic, but ready-to-use solutions exist.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: If you go e.g. to the [three js docs for the sphere](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry) and increase the amount of vertices a bit, you will see the "lines" all end in two singularities at the poles. There are other ways to do this, e.g. a football doesn't have such poles. Distributing vertices perfectly equidistant on a sphere is a topic with lots of papers, issues, etc.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I looked for that kind of thing before coming here to ask but as you can see, googling alternatives https://www.google.com/search?q=three.js+alternatives+to+sphere+geometry&oq=three.js+alternatives+to+sphere+geometry comes up plain empty (nothing related to alternatives), and I've reworded my search as many ways as I can think of. Do you know of any specific projects I could try or better search terms to find them?

Comment: [some](http://extremelearning.com.au/evenly-distributing-points-on-a-sphere/) [articles](https://rreusser.github.io/fibonacci-sphere/) [about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358046/is-the-fibonacci-lattice-the-very-best-way-to-evenly-distribute-n-points-on-a-sp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a [fibonacci sphere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26127012/128511)

```
function fibonacciSphere(numPoints, point) {
  const rnd = 1;
  const offset = 2 / numPoints;
  const increment = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));

  const y = ((point * offset) - 1) + (offset / 2);
  const r = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(y, 2));

  const phi = (point + rnd) % numPoints * increment;

  const x = Math.cos(phi) * r;
  const z = Math.sin(phi) * r;

  return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

Example:

```js
function fibonacciSphere(numPoints, point) {
  const rnd = 1;
  const offset = 2 / numPoints;
  const increment = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));

  const y = ((point * offset) - 1) + (offset / 2);
  const r = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(y, 2));

  const phi = (point + rnd) % numPoints * increment;

  const x = Math.cos(phi) * r;
  const z = Math.sin(phi) * r;

  return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
}

function main() {
  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  function addTextNode(text, vert) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'label';
    div.textContent = text;
    div.style.marginTop = '-1em';
    const label = new THREE.CSS2DObject(div);
    label.position.copy(vert);
    scene.add(label);
  }

  const renderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  const container = document.querySelector('#c');
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  const numPoints = 50;
  for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
    addTextNode(`p${i}`, fibonacciSphere(numPoints, i));
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    // three's poor choice of how to hanlde size strikes again :(
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight); 
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
.label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: I was scared of this when I saw it because I dont have a good understanding of math / geometry but I simply multiplied the X, Y, Z by the size of my sphere in THREE.js and poof, perfectly aligned. You're a wizard.

Comment: I wish I could take credit but I got this from the linked answer who got it from Fibonacci

Comment: Well thanks for sharing, it may have taken lots of time to track down. Result: https://i.gyazo.com/809e07098b87f76bfca422bf6d62f8b4.mp4

Comment: Thank you! Helped me make an atom nucleus with n amount of protons. Still have to figure out how to make a bigger radius.