# How to make a nested for loop for cylinders around a sphere(coronavirus) in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops, p5.js

I'm pretty new and learning p5.js, and I am trying to make a 3D coronavirus in p5.js with a sphere and a bunch of cylinders..

You can see my sketch here: https://editor.p5js.org/zzzzzij/sketches/frE9-37R

```js
    var sketch = function (p) {
      with(p) {

        let angle = 0;

        p.setup = function() {
          createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
        };
    
        p.draw = function() {
          ambientLight(255);
          background(175);
          noStroke();
          rotateY(angle);
          rotateZ(angle*0.8);
          normalMaterial();

          push();
          rotateY(PI);
          sphere(100);
          pop();

          push();
          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/6);
            push();
            translate (0, -21*5, 0*5);
            rotateY(PI/18);
            rotateX(0);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/5);
            push();
            translate (0, -19*5, 9*5);
            rotateY(PI/18);
            rotateX(-PI/8);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/4);
            push();
            translate (0, -15*5, 15*5);
            rotateY(PI/18);
            rotateX(-PI/4);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/3);
            push();
            translate (0, -9*5, 19*5);
            rotateY(PI/18);
            rotateX(-PI/2.5);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          }  
            
          for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            rotateZ(0);
            push();
            translate (0, 0*5, 21*5);
            rotateY(0);
            rotateX(-PI/2);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            rotateZ(0);
            push();
            translate (0, 0*5, -21*5);
            rotateY(0);
            rotateX(-PI/2);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/3);
            push();
            translate (0, 9*5, -19*5);
            rotateY(-PI/18);
            rotateX(-PI/2.5);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/4);
            push();
            translate (0, 15*5, -15*5);
            rotateY(-PI/18);
            rotateX(-PI/4);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 

          for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
            rotateZ(PI/5);
            push();
            translate (0, 19*5, -9*5);
            rotateY(-PI/18);
            rotateX(-PI/8);
            cylinder (6, 20);
            pop();
          } 
          
          pop();
            
          angle+=0.01;
        };
     
      }
    };
    
    let node = document.createElement('div');
    window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
    new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
<div id="p5-container"></div>
```

Since I need every cylinder to point to a different direction, I've come up with using a bunch of for loops, doing one belt of cylinders after another spaced out along Z axis, every time the loop shrinks and rotates along X and Y a bit more.

As you can see, this has resulted for me in 7 for loops. And 3 of them just have some negative values of the other 3 to complete the ball.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to write these for loops in a nested loop?
I've thought through it but just couldn't think of a solution...

Or if anyone has a better way to write these cylinder loops?

Thank you!

Comment: After some research, I think I should go for the fractal tree approach instead of this for loop...gonna keep trying here ;)

Comment: See the answers to the question [Evenly distributing n points on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9600801/50065).

Comment: Have you considered using vectors to draw your sphere. Then you can have one for loop and draw a cylinder at the origin of each vector? Here are two video tutorials you might find helpful [Spherical Geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkuBWEkBrZA) and [Terrain Generation with Perlin Noise in Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution. What I have done in the following code, is that I first calculated the position of each vertex according to the number of `total` vertices and store them in a 2D array called `globe`! This will allow you to store information that can be used later in the code to draw the sphere and cylinders in a singular for-loop (each)!

I then created a sphere using triangles (in other words vertices, edges and faces) from the information stored in `globe`. You will notice that instead of cylinders I draw spheres. If you try changing that to cylinders it won't look very attractive. I'm not very good at mathematics but you can fix that issue by calculating the `normals` of each vertex. You may find this  [A Unit Vector (Normalize) - The Nature of Code](https://youtu.be/ttz05d8DSOs) and [normalize()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/normalize) helpful but keep in mind that you will need to convert that from 2D to 3D!

```js
const globe = []; //Holds a 2D array of vectors (v1,v2)
const r = 70; //Radius of circle
const total = 15; //number of vertices
let angleX = 0; //Rotate X axis
let angleY = 0; //Rotate Y axis

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 200, WEBGL);

  //Calculate vectors according to number of vertices given
  for (let i = 0; i < total + 1; i++) {
    globe[i] = []; //Create 2D array to hold vertices
    const lat = map(i, 0, total, 0, PI);
    for (let j = 0; j < total + 1; j++) {
      const lon = map(j, 0, total, 0, TWO_PI);
      const x = r * sin(lat) * cos(lon);
      const y = r * sin(lat) * sin(lon);
      const z = r * cos(lat);
      globe[i][j] = createVector(x, y, z); //Store vertices in 2D array
    }
  }
}

function draw(){
  background(51);
  rotateX(angleX);
  rotateY(angleY);
  fill(255);
  stroke(1);
  //Draw Sphere using globe 2D array
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (let j = 0; j < total + 1; j++) {
      const v1 = globe[i][j];
      vertex(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
      const v2 = globe[i + 1][j];
      vertex(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
      vertices = [v1,v2];
    }
    endShape();
  }
  
  //Draw Cylinders
  for (i = 0; i < total; i ++) {
    for (j = 0; j < total; j ++) {
      const v1 = globe[i][j];
      const v2 = globe[i + 1][j];
      
      push();
      noStroke();
      translate(v1.x,v1.y,v1.z)
      
      normalMaterial();
      sphere(3,5);
      pop();
    }
  } 
  
  //Rotate on X & Y axes 
  angleX += 0.005;
  angleY += 0.006;
  
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```