# Obtaining a region of evenly distributed points on a sphere

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

There are several questions on this site about distributing points on the surface of a sphere, but all of these are based on actually generating all of the points on that sphere. My favorite thus far is the golden spiral discussed in [Evenly distributing n points on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere).

I need to cover a sphere in trillions of points, but only ever need to actually generate a tiny region of the surface (earth down to ~10 meters, looking at a roughly 1 km^2 area). The points generated for that region must match the points that would be generated for the entire sphere (i.e., stitching small regions together must yield the same result as generating a larger region), and generation should be pretty fast.

My attempts to use the golden spiral with such a large number of points have been thwarted by floating point precision issues.

The best I've managed to come up with is generating points at equally spaced latitudes and calculating longitudinal spacing based on the circumference at that latitude. The result is far from satisfactory however (especially the resulting horizontal rings of points).

Does anyone have a suggestion for generating a small region of distributed points on the surface of a sphere?

Comment: Why don't you use simply a grid? Georeferenced systems are full of such things... Also, using terms like `equally spaced` on a sphere is a bit problematic... Unless you're think only in arc, and not in length. For 10 meters resolution on Earth, you'll be fine with a grid spaced each quarter of seconds. It's far from being a problem with floating point precision - worst case, use integers and fixed-point computing.
Regarding speed... A simple Lat/Lon grid (even with 1/4 sec precision) is near nothing. Only 5 millions points per axis, worldwide. Any decent GIS handle that easily.

Comment: Not trillions, though.  1 sq km at ~10m resolution is nowhere near trillions. Closer to 10,000 points, I think.

Comment: I would use [Sphere triangulation by mesh subdivision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214) where you start with icosahedron and after each recursive split use only triangles inside your region of interest ...

Comment: @Wisblade Simply using a grid results in very different distances near the poles vs. the equator.

Comment: @danh ~5 trillion points covering the entire sphere, of which only a region of ~10k points is needed at a time.

Comment: I don't understand what "earth down to ~10 meters, looking at a roughly 1 km^2 area" mean.

Comment: @Stef I meant a sphere the size of the earth, with points spaced roughly 10 meters apart on the surface. The square kilometer refers to the region of interest for which to actually generate the points, i.e., only the ~10,000 points within that region should be generated, not the ~5 trillion points needed to cover the entire earth.

Comment: @zennehoy Thanks, I know. That's why I wrote "unless you think only in arc". It's a problem that absolutely NO projection system ever solved, not for the entire globe at once. Is it a _**REAL**_ problem to have a higher density of points near poles? If so, use bands like DTED if it's really a huge issue. Or explain what do you need these points for - because it seems quite like a wrong answer to a false problem, for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertices of a [geodesic sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron) would work well in this application.

You start with an icosahedron, divide each face into a triangular mesh of whatever resolution you like, and project the points onto the surface of the sphere.

Comment: I ended up using this with some random displacement to eliminate the lines of points along the latitudes, while maintaining the overall point density.

Answer (score 2):

The [Fibonacci sphere approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127012/177931) is quite easy to generalize efficiently to a subset of points computation, as the analytic formulas are very straight-forward.

The below code computes the subset of points shown below for a trillion points in a few seconds of runtime on my weak laptop and a relatively under optimised python implementation.

[image: A small subset of points from a trillion points computed quickly]

Code to compute the above is below, and includes a means to verify the subset computation is exactly the same as a brute-force computation (however don't try it for trillion points, it will never finish unless you have a super-computer!)

Please note, the use of 128-bit doubles is an absolute *requirement* when you do the computation over more than about a billion points as there are major quantisation artefacts otherwise!

Runtime scales with `r' * N` where `r'` is the ratio of the subset to that of the full sphere. Thus, a very small `r'` can be computed very efficiently.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as ax3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def fibonacci_sphere_pts(num_pts):
  ga = (3 - np.sqrt(5)) * np.pi  # golden angle

  # Create a list of golden angle increments along tha range of number of points
  theta = ga * np.arange(num_pts)

  # Z is a split into a range of -1 to 1 in order to create a unit circle
  z = np.linspace(1 / num_pts - 1, 1 - 1 / num_pts, num_pts)

  # a list of the radii at each height step of the unit circle
  radius = np.sqrt(1 - z * z)

  # Determine where xy fall on the sphere, given the azimuthal and polar angles
  y = radius * np.sin(theta)
  x = radius * np.cos(theta)

  return np.asarray(list(zip(x,y,z)))


def fibonacci_sphere(num_pts):
  x,y,z = zip(*fibonacci_sphere_subset(num_pts))

  # Display points in a scatter plot
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
  ax.scatter(x, y, z)
  plt.show()

def fibonacci_sphere_subset_pts(num_pts, p0, r0 ):
  """
  Get a subset of a full fibonacci_sphere
  """
  ga = (3 - np.sqrt(5)) * np.pi  # golden angle

  x0, y0, z0 = p0

  z_s = 1 / num_pts - 1
  z_e = 1 - 1 / num_pts

  # linspace formula for range [z_s,z_e] for N points is 
  # z_k = z_s +  (z_e - z_s) / (N-1) * k , for k [0,N)
  # therefore k = (z_k - z_s)*(N-1) / (z_e - z_s)
  # would be the closest value of k
  k = int(np.round((z0 - z_s) * (num_pts - 1) / (z_e - z_s)))

  # here a sufficient number of "layers" of the fibonacci sphere must be
  # selected to obtain enough points to be a superset of the subset given the
  # radius, we use a heuristic to determine the number but it can be obtained
  # exactly by the correct formula instead (by choosing an upperbound)
  dz = (z_e - z_s) / (num_pts-1)
  n_dk = int(np.ceil( r0 / dz ))

  dk = np.arange(k - n_dk, k + n_dk+1)
  dk = dk[np.where((dk>=0)&(dk<num_pts))[0]]

  # NOTE: *must* use long double over regular doubles below, otherwise there
  # are major quantization errors in the output for large number of points
  theta = ga * dk.astype(np.longdouble)
  z = z_s + (z_e - z_s ) / (num_pts-1) *dk
  radius = np.sqrt(1 - z * z)
  y = radius * np.sin(theta)
  x = radius * np.cos(theta)
  idx = np.where(np.square(x - x0) + np.square(y-y0) + np.square(z-z0) <= r0*r0)[0]
  return x[idx],y[idx],z[idx]

def fibonacci_sphere_subset(num_pts, p0, r0, do_compare=False ):
  """
  Display fib sphere subset points and optionally compare against bruteforce computation
  """

  x,y,z = fibonacci_sphere_subset_pts(num_pts,p0,r0)

  if do_compare:
    subset = zip(x,y,z)
    subset_bf = fibonacci_sphere_pts(num_pts)
    x0,y0,z0 = p0
    subset_bf = [ (x,y,z) for (x,y,z) in subset_bf if np.square(x - x0) + np.square(y-y0) + np.square(z-z0) <= r0*r0  ]
    subset_bf = np.asarray(subset_bf)
    if np.allclose(subset,subset_bf):
        print('PASS: subset and bruteforce computation agree completely')
    else:
        print('FAIL: subset and bruteforce computation DO NOT agree completely')

  # Display points in a scatter plot
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
  ax.scatter(x, y, z)
  plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="fibonacci sphere")
  parser.add_argument(
      "numpts", type=int, help="number of points to distribute along sphere"
  )
  args = parser.parse_args()
  # hard-coded point to query with a tiny fixed radius
  p0 = (.5,.5,np.sqrt(1. - .5*.5 - .5*.5)) # coordinate of query point representing center of subset, note all coordinates fall between -1 and 1
  r0 = .00001 # the radius of the subset, a very small number is chosen as radius of full sphere is 1.0
  fibonacci_sphere_subset(int(args.numpts),p0,r0,do_compare=False)
```

Comment: I've been playing with this for a while, and while I continue to like the results, unfortunately this only solves the problem in one and not both dimensions. As a result, it is too slow for what I need. Definitely an up-vote though!

Comment: The formulas can be vastly refined to the point of calculating this for a very small # of points, what I posted here is a very basic version. If interested I could derive much tighter bounds around the area of interest.

Comment: How would you go about reducing the number of points along a section of the spiral? As is, the entire section of the spiral is generated, which is equivalent to a certain range of latitudes ("layers"). How would you limit the range of longitudes generated?

Comment: The math involved is not too complex, it's definitely possible through a variety of techniques.